# SQL Server trigger for a specific column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a production table called `Status` with columns shown below including a few sample lines:

```
Id  TaskOriginator  AssignedTo  Status
--------------------------------------
1   CANDYC  EBEKE0  Approved
2   UPOFA0  CANDYC  Approved
3   PKOOP0  EBEKE0  Approved
4   UPOFA0  PKOOP0  Approved
5   PKOOP0  RVDWE0  Completed
6   PKOOP0  RVDWE0  Completed
7   PKOOP0  RVDWE0  Completed
8   PKOOP0  RVDWE0  Completed
9   PKOOP0  RVDWE0  Completed
10  PKOOP0  RVDWE0  Completed
```

Now when a new line gets inserted it gets the status new, then a action happens and the `assignedTo` column gets updated with a name, now I want to have a trigger on this `assignedTo` column, if the status is new and the assigned to column gets updated to one of the following person's (e.g. `FBOJE0`, `ASWARTZ` or `EDEWAAL`) then a mail should be send via the trigger.

How will you go about doing a trigger like this, without locking the table for inserts or updates by other processes?

Comment: you should keep the email outside the trigger. The trigger will lock the row until the email is sent. Triggers are not good for emailing. Why not do a dtsx that checks for that condition periodically, and sends the emails?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the trigger will always run, so minimize what it will do from the start. Within your trigger, check if the column is updated:

```
create trigger trgTableIU on Table for insert , update
AS
BEGIN
        if update (assignedTo) 
        BEGIN
             select i.id,i.assignedto into #usethese from inserted i join deleted d on i.id=d.id and i.assignedto in ('FBOJE0','ASWARTZ','EDEWAAL') where i.status<>d.status and i.status not in ('new')
             if @@rowcount > 0
             BEGIN
                 --final mail stuff goes here 
                 --OR better yet, move to a working table that a job reviews every minute for records in working table
             END
        END
END
```

As a side note, triggers were amazing when I first started, but they usually end up being your enemy over time. (oh what is just one other quick check or process here...). You should avoid when possible and when used just set quick review flags with minimal filters in the trigger that another job will come through and process.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

You *can* do what you want using an after update trigger.

However, I would discourage you from taking this approach.  It sounds like you have a set of complex requirements for your application.  Instead, I would suggest that you have a stored procedure that does updates.  This stored procedure can then do all the logic that you want -- and you don't have to worry about locking at all.

Why do I prefer a stored procedure over a trigger?  The reasons are primarily maintainability.  Here are a few:

- By default, SQL Server Management Studio does not script triggers on a table.
- If the table is deleted (say accidentally), all triggers get deleted.  Recreating the table doesn't recreate the trigger, necessarily.
- Redefining a trigger as an `INSTEAD OF` trigger has drastic performance effects.
- A stored procedure can do many other things, such as returning an error message back to the calling routine.
- As the logic gets complicated, the limitations of triggers may impact your design decisions (such as no dynamic SQL) and functionality.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the feedback Gordon, I don't have access to the SP, since its maintained by another program, I just want to be able to notify my users via email that a status has changed hence the trigger :)